# Iphone Posting on wall with FBConnect

Tags: iphone, facebook

I am using the latest facebook sdk. 
Everything works fine even the post on wall feature.
Thing is that the post to wall dialog contains minimal information. Just a textbox and a small label reading "... via app-name".

I have used the sample code snippet which provides things like 'caption' and 'description' but these are NOT shown in the post to wall dialog.

I have seen other apps with captions, descriptions and even a large image attached to the post.

How can I show these objects (caption, description, image etc..) using the facebook sdk ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't use the Facebook SDK so I just send POST requests with the necessary values.  Similar to this:
[Posting on Facebook Tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/1626/how-to-post-to-a-users-wall-upload-photos-and-add-a-like-button-from-your-iphone-app)

There's another tutorial on the same blog that does use the SDK:
[Posting with the Facebook SDK](http://www.raywenderlich.com/77/how-to-post-on-facebook-with-your-iphone-app)